# Adding new record in access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to enable a few fields when i click on the Add button on my form.I have change the onclick to `Event Procedure` to be able to add the following code

```
Category_Desc.Enabled = True
```

My Category field get enable as expected but the Add button no long work

```
Private Sub add_Click()
Category_Desc.Enabled = True
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: According to your code, if your Category field gets enabled, your button works.

Comment: @Gustav i have a Category_ID field that is not enabled but when i click on the add , the category is do not turn to `(new)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to go to a new record, include this command:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord, , acNewRec
```

Also, if you wish to have Category enabled only on a new record, remove that code from the Add button and replace it with this line in the OnCurrent event of the form:

```
Category_Desc.Enabled = Me.NewRecord
```

Comment: The first command work flawlessly...how does the command chnage if i want to delete a record...can you link me to a tutorial

Comment: You can use this command:   DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord     - lots of tutorials are on-line, just bing/google on the keywords.

Comment: @Gustav...Thanks for giving me the right keywords ...it solved my issues.Kind regards